System.UnauthorizedAccessException error when trying to create a folder or file on a drive I mounted using DokanNet version 2.1.0
working on a virtual file system project with .net 8.0, I need to mount a drive and then create files and folders in the mounted drive.
I'm using DokanNet version 2.1.0 library to mount the drive but when I try to create a folder with code or manually in the mounted drive I get error: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'E:\testFolder' is denied.'
How can I successfully create folders and files on the mounted drive
I have tried running my visual studio as an administrator but I still got the same error, I have also tried mounting in different location but got the same error.

can you run the exe file that appears when you run it as debug or relase as an administrator and see if it creates a file? There is also a document showing how to check file permissions from the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_IO_Directory_SetAccessControl_System_String_System_Security_AccessControl_DirectorySecurity_
